# How to stop supporting iOS7

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have just installed Xcode 5, and I have an application that should be targeted only to iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.1 devices.

How can I stop supporting iOS 7.0 ??

Comment: You can't. If you build for iOS6 then anything with 6 or higher can run it. What do you mean by "stop supporting"? Do you not want them to install it?

Comment: You can't stop supporting newer versions. Imagine you have a user of your app that upgrades to iOS 7 and then finds that the apps (that he has possibly paid for) suddenly stop working?

Comment: Can't I do it manually in code??

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, stopping an iOS 7 user from installing my app may help, or anyway that helps me restrict my app only to iOS 6 and iOs 6.1 users.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible, you can stop supporting previous versions of iOS, but not the other way. You need to prepare your app to work on iOS7.

YOu don't need to redesign your app or anything, just open in with XCode 5 and get rid of all the warnings/small bugs.

Comment: Some UI issues aren't small bugs, and can take a considerable amount of effort to fix. I imagine this question is leaning towards getting the iOS6 SDK running in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you can't "not support iOS 7". However, you *can delay* upgrading to the iOS 7 SDK (at least, in the short term).

To do such, simply continue using Xcode 4 to build your app. When you're ready to submit it, simply do such using Xcode 4 like you normally would.

For the time being, Apple will *most likely* accept apps built using the iOS 6 SKD. (Imagine, for example, that you've spent several months or a year building your app... Apple will still let you submit it *for the time being* even using an older SDK).

Further, the app will run and appear correctly (in many/most cases) using iOS 6 UI components *for the most part* (in example, `UIAlertView` is an exception to this, which will use the iOS 7's `UIAlertView` look).

In the long term, however, you really should convert your app to use the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to prevent the installation of your app to devices that meet minimum version requirements.

Of course, you're free to check in your app the iOS version and do something about that. For example, if your concern is really that the user user should download another, iOS 7-designed version of your app, you can inform her about this possibility:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     if ([self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) // iOS 7
          ... // redirect user to better, tint-enabled version
     return YES;
}
```